# How to select all checkbox if data status is 1 in angular2?

Tags: angular

I am working on anglar4 application.
If json data status is 1 so display the checkbox and visa versa.

**Component.ts:-**

```
this.names = [
    {
       "name":"Jonny"
       "status":1
    },
    {
       "name":"Rahul"
       "status":0
    },
    {
       "name":"Jimmy"
       "status":0
    },
    {
       "name":"Harry"
       "status":1
    },
    {
       "name":"Vina"
       "status":0
    }
  ]
```

**Component.html:-**

```
<ul>
  <li> <input type="checkbox"/> All
  </li>
  <li *ngFor="let n of names"> 
   <span *ngIf="n.status">
    <input type="checkbox">
   </span>
  {{n.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

How to check all checkbox if status is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just use operator `ngIf="n.status === '1'"`

```
<span *ngIf="n.status === '1'">
    <input type="checkbox">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check All on one check of 'all'

**Component :**

```
checkAll(checked : boolean) {
    for(let name in names) {
        name.status = checked ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

**Template :**

```
<ul>
  <li> <input type="checkbox" (change)='checkAll($event.target.checked)'/> All
  </li>
  <li *ngFor="let n of names"> 
   <span *ngIf="n.status">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{n.name}}" [(ngModel)]="n.status">
   </span>
  {{n.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

This will show all the checkbox checked with status 1 :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{n.name}}" [(ngModel)]="n.status">
```

Comment: In this code checkbox is check so does not display? Checkbox is show if all checked or unchecked.

Comment: *ngIf="n.status" , hide all unchecked checkbox , but if you check main checkbox , it will check all the checkbox and show all the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

This will display all checkbox checked when the condition **n.status === 1**

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let n of names"> 
        <span *ngIf="n.status == 1">
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="n.status == 1">
        </span>{{n.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```